# sccm2012 client.msi error during OSD

Tags: sccm-2012

I need some help understand my client.msi log to work out why my OSD is failing.

**Let me first tell you the scenario**

I have a Task Sequence in sccm 2012, it takes a standard win 7 enterprise image.
Applies drivers, changes the install from d:\to c:\ *(by setting OSDPreservedDisk=FALSE, and Specify logical drive letter= C:)*  then installs 15 applications(java, acrobat. etc)
**This works.**

Then I installed windows 7 enterprise to a virtual machine, fully windows updated it, sysprepped and captured, It was installed to d:\Windows
Just like the install.wim is.
Then I replaced the original .wim from the enterprise DVD, with the newly captured one.

**So to sum up:** only thing that changes between working and not working is the image.
from standard install.wim from the win7 cd, to a captured image

now my Client errors and aborts before applying applications:
(took the liberty of translating a few places)

```
**Property(S): PrimaryVolumePath = C:
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Note: 1: 1729
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Transforming table Error.
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Transforming table Error.
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Transforming table Error.
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Transforming table Error.
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Transforming table Error.
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Transforming table Error.
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Produkt: Configuration Manager Client -- Konfigurationen mislykkedes. = Product: Configuration Manager Client -- Configuration Failed
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Windows Installer har konfigureret produktet igen. Produktnavn: Configuration Manager Client. Produktversion: = Windows installer has configured the product again

5.00.7804.1000. Produktsprog: 1030. Producent: Microsoft Corporation. Produktet blev konfigureret igen eller fejlstatus: 1603.
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Attempting to delete file C:\WINDOWS\Installer\24f2f.mst
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Unable to delete the file. LastError = 32
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: Attempting to delete file C:\WINDOWS\Installer\24f2f.mst
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:978]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:993]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
 MSI (s) (C0:C8) [13:03:55:993]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
 === Logføring stoppet: 12-11-2013  13:03:55 ===**
```

I understand it happens when I'm trying to install to c:..
But what is really weird to me is this next part -->

****NOTE!!!:** if I set 'OSDPreserveredDisk=TRUE' . the new image is installed to d:\ and all apps are added, so its in the process of placing it on the c:\ something is wrong**

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say the real problem is trying to work around the wim being installed to the D: drive. This is because the install.wim from the DVD is being used for installation.

Microsoft's recommendation is this: Import the install.wim file into sccm as an Operating System *Installer*, (*not* Operating System *Image*). Create a new task sequence to lay this installer down, update, install apps, etc, then sysprep and capture. For best results, let sccm sysprep and capture the image.

*Then*, import the wim created from this task sequence as an Operating System *Image*, and use this for deployment. This wim should install to the C: with no <s>hacks</s> workarounds, and the error above *should* go away.

As for the cause of your error, as you probably know if your msi doesn't return 0 (successful) or 3010 (restart required) then the task sequence will fail, unless

1. You're running a command line step and tell it what error codes to expect
2. You explicitly tell sccm to continue on error for that step.

A thread being ran by your msi is returning a 32 which appears to cause the msi installer to return a 1603 back to sccm, which kills your ts. It is probably hardcoded to delete something from C:\Windows\Installer, or an environment variable is returning that path, either way I would redo it, because patching this could be like playing whackamole, with other problems cropping up in the future.

Comment: Well I actually did make a task sequence from SCCM2012
That deployed the install.wim

Comment: It's possible, I don't know if sccm's sysprep does anything beyond run `sysprep` from the command line with switches, but I've had the same problems and some of them were resolved by just going that route. The thing is your newly captured wim shouldn't install to the D: drive anymore, you shouldn't have to set extra ts variables or anything, it should just lay to the next available partition (assuming you format the disk to a single partition..?), which would be the C: drive.

Comment: MDMoore

I created a task sequence to deploy install.wim from the CD..
And just installed it to a virtual machine.., no modifications made.

It installed to d:\windows .. 
Then I sysprepped and captured that image

What you suggest is it will at some point pick c:\ itself.. when is that suppose to happen? cause it doesn't here

Comment: Yep, when you lay down your captured .wim it should install to C: on it's own. if it doesn't, you should let sccm automate the build and capture process by booting your vm to sccm pxe, and running your build and capture task sequence.

Comment: and could that be caused cause the install.wim is imported as system image? and not system process?

Cause my regular install.wim does not install as c:\ ..

Comment: install.wim from the dvd is not supposed to install to C:, this is by design.

Comment: I dont understand why it should install to c:\ on its own
Its being captured from a d:\ partition and 
by standard OSDPReserveDriveLetter is set to 'TRUE'

That would have it install again to d:\ .. I see multiple people saying the same thing if I google it ?

Comment: Lets say I wanna do it like yo say it.
I haven't tried sysprepping and capturing from the task sequence
How would I make the changed and installations of programs I would like before it sysprepped and captured!?